# saving data in html5 storages with select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a select menu which dont needs and submit button
On top of this site
[چت روم موبایل](http://tntclub.ir/chat/)

now i wanna a code (like this) save data (for example X) in html5 storages(databse) when user selectes any of them (per select  we have an id that will saved)

Comment: Here is better ex. http://tntclub.ir/users/MiLaD

Comment: so you want the selected value saved in the browser's localStorage?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.